# Error with detailTextLabel from NSArray in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a Table View with the Detail Right style of cells (prototype cells).  In implementing the self.detailLabelText.text on an array I have I'm receiving an error message when I attempt to load the table.  Below is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }

    switch (pickerSelection)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [visitList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.detailTextLabel.text = [windows1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [visitList2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.detailTextLabel.text = [windows2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;

    }
    return cell;
}
```

I'm receiving the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

The table loads correctly with the main textLabel, and I can load a string after `cell.detailTextLabel =` so I know that my setup is correct.  I also can NSLog both of the arrays I'm trying to load, just not in the detailLabelText.

I know the error message has to due with the expected length of an array, I just can't figure out what or where.  Sorry for an elementary question.  I'm a noob.

UPDATE: Here is my numberOfRowsInSelection method:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    switch (pickerSelection)
    {
        case 0:
            return [visitList1 count];
            return [windows1 count];            
            break;
        case 1:
            return [visitList2 count];
            return [windows2 count];
            break;


    }

    return 10;
}
```

Each of the arrays have over 3 items.  i threw that last "return 10;" in there just in case something wasn't working right with the switch statement, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Update 2:  When I replace my windows1 array with static strings they populate in the detail area of the table.  That's great (although I now seem to have some sort of problem with my original window arrays).

Comment: Can you put up for tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method?

Comment: NSLog the array contents and array count in both of the delegate methods - the issue will go transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `windows1` array or `windows2` array only has 2 items in it, and your table datasource is telling it there are 3 rows to display. As Kevin asked, edit your question with the `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method you implemented, as the problem is almost certainly in there.

Comment: this was true.  The array windows1 hadn't been fully populated yet.  Thanks.

Comment: @Craigvu You should mark the question answered when someone has helped you. Otherwise your reputation will not improve and people will be less likely to help.